# Database design help. Many to many creates an association table, correct?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm designing a very simple database for my application and it's configured like this:

```
Employee
Carnet
Name
LastName

Area
Name

Document
ID
Employee (FK)
Project (FK)

Project
ID
Company (FK)
Title

Company
Name
CEO (FK)
NIT

Person
Carnet
Name
Lastname
```

Now the gist of this question is, an **Area** can have many **Document**; and a **Document** can belong to many **Area**.

This I'm told, creates a third relationship table, correct?

What would go in that table and would this be able to work if I'm going to be using Linq-to-SQL as the only tool for accessing my database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... You'd have a table called AreaDocuments with columns called AreaID and DocumentId. This kind of relationship is M x N where M instances can be associated to N instances and vice-versa.

Sample data:

```
AreaId      DocumentId
1           1
1           2
2           1
2           2
```

How to handle it in code:

```
Document document1 = new Document();
document1.Id = 1;
document1.Title = "Whatever";

Document document2 = new Document();
document2.Id = 2;
document2.Title = "Whatever";

Area area1 = new Area();
area1.Documents.Add(document1);
area1.Documents.Add(document2);

Area area2 = new Area();
area2.Documents.Add(document1);
area2.Documents.Add(document2);
```

This link [How to implement a many-to-many relationship using Linq to Sql?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mitsu/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-linq-to-sql) can provide more information about using this kind of relationship in LINQ to SQL.